# Pandas: performance comparison in dropping NA entries

Tags: pandas, performance

I run into a piece of code aimed at dropping NA values in a dataframe:

```
df = df[df[‘a’]==df[‘a’]
```

Instead I would use:

```
df.dropna(subset=[‘a’], inplace=True)
```

The resulting dataframe is the same, but which one is the most suitable in terms of memory usage, computational cost, and execution time?

I also considered the possibility of reading the source code of the [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method, to understand whether there are temporary created dataframe...

Comment: the second one is definitely more explicit and likely more robust as the first one relies on a peculiarity of NaN to be non equal to itself. Plus you can handle many more parameters (several columns in `subset`, threshold, etc.). Jut use the second one!

Comment: Perhaps measure it to get a (crude) baseline?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.